# subplots_adjust in matplotlib does not work in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code that did not work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make the plot
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(3.27, 6))
axs[0].plot(range(5), range(5), label='label 1')
axs[0].plot(range(5), range(4, -1, -1), label='label 2')
axs[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.1, 1., 0.1), mode='expand', ncol=2, frameon=True, borderaxespad=0.)

# Adjust subplots to make room
fig.subplots_adjust(top=.5)

fig.savefig('test.png', format='png', dpi=300)
```

It can be seen that the fig.subplots_adjust did not work at all.

I am using WinPython 3.3.2.3 64 bit, with matplotlib version 1.3.0 and CPython 3.3. This happened in IPython Notebook. The backend is the in-line one. The output from the notebook is complete, but the output file is improperly cropped. In both notebook & saved file, the subplots_adjust command has no effect.

[image: The output of the above code]

Comment: is this what you see in the note book, or what it saves?

Comment: @tcaswell This is what it saves. What I see in the notebook is quite normal - I can see the whole plot but still subplots_adjust does not take effect at all. Thanks for asking a good question!

Comment: is this in-line or not?  What does `matplotlib.get_backend()` return?

Comment: @tcaswell This is in-line. matplotlib.get_backend() returns: 'module://IPython.kernel.zmq.pylab.backend_inline'

Comment: Suspect that this is a limitation of that backend, but I am not sure.  Please include that detail in the main body of your question.

Comment: @tcaswell Thanks a lot! I have edited the post accordingly. The question is - I tried to specify matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg') and the problem remains, even though it is a different backend.

Comment: did you make sure to call `use` before you imported `pyplot`?

Comment: @tcaswell Yes I did... Hmm. I ran this code under pure python (not ipython) and it still did not get the output right. Would you think of any workaround for this?

Comment: Not sure, because it works properly for me (but with python 2.7).

Comment: @tcaswell Thanks a lot for your help! And also, interestingly, though it still happens when I use ipython-qtconsole command to run the whole script yesterday, this problem did not happen when I close the ipython-notebook and start with a fresh ipython. subplots_adjust() just cannot run on ipython notebook, and it somehow impacted some hidden-settings. I got my problem solved by using qtconsole, but I am really surprised that it did not happen for qtconsole - I thought the qtconsole and the notebook are both using the in-line backend, and are really close enough.

Comment: Please post that last comment as the answer.  If you have not re-started python, changing backends does not always work like you think it will.

Comment: @tcaswell I think you're right. I will post the solution right now. Thanks again Tom!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of tcaswell, I got it solved by entirely closing the IPython Notebook and re-run the code via the ipython-qtconsole. It seems that the subplots_adjust() simply doesn't work for python 3 in ipython-notebook. I am new to python, and is really interested in what difference is there between the qtconsole and the notebook, backend-wise, if anyone has got ideas.

Anyways - good to have this problem solved!